# Sewer Terminator model from Genisys?

Tags: the-terminator, the-terminator-series

what was the model of sewer terminator that john connor killed while saving kyle reese in Terminator:Genisys?

Answer (score 2):

It was a 600 series.  You can tell because its skin was rubbery and clearly fake, an indicator that it's a T-600, the first infiltrator model.

Also, the scene had a callback to the Resistance's future use of dogs to detect Terminators vs. humans.

Comment: tnx, i thought so as well.. besides, T800 were new at the time kyle reese was sent to 1984 so we are probably correct... i found some comments that it is T800 cause of the plasma rifles but i don't think so...